# How can I prevent accidentally quitting an application?

Tags: shutdown, user-account, adium, applications

I use [Adium](http://adium.im/), but if I set a "Quit Confirmation" in the advanced preferences, it cancels log out. If I don't, it is way too easy to quit it, since it gets focused between apps sometimes.

Is there any way I can have a "Quit Confirmation" show up when I try to quit Adium, except when I am logging out or shutting down the OS?

[image]

Comment: Would it be enough to remove the command-Q shortcut for Quit?

Comment: @GEdgar If it is only for the App in question, sure.

Comment: To disable quit for all apps see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/205742/109005).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do the following to make it a little bit harder to quit Adium by accident. I think this should solve your problem.

Start by opening System Preferences > Keyboard.

[image: System Preferences Keyboard]

1. Click Keyboard Shortcuts in the pillbox above.
2. Make sure you have `Application Shortcuts` selected in the left bar.
3. Click the <kbd>+</kbd> button to add a new shortcut.

[image: Add Keyboard Shortcut]

4. Select Adium from the Application dropdown.
5. Type "Quit" in the menu title field.
6. Put your cursor in the Keyboard Shortcut field and type <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>
7. Click Add

[image: Add Adium shortcut]

And you're done. You can close your System Preferences because the Quit command in Adium has been remapped to a less-likely-to-be-accidentally-typed shortcut.