# Remapping command Q to another shortcut for quitting apps

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut, keybindings, applications

This has been an ongoing frustration for me, and I think for a lot of people in the community who use the keyboard a lot. Shortcuts like <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> are an everyday stroke for lots of apps. I am not sure what went into the decision for mac to assign <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> to quit.

Any way to get around this? I basically want to disable <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> which I have already done by following [How to disable command-Q for Quit?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/78948/how-to-disable-command-q-for-quit). However, I also like to reassign the quit command to another keystroke **systemwide**. I saw several answers on assigning it per app and I don't like this. Probably reassign it to <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>.

I read and searched already but can't seem to find the right answer. I saw this karabiner rule in this answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/90827/260534, I'm not sure if it would work but I can't use it since it's in XML. The version I'm running, 11.1.0, is using json. I'd appreciate if someone can have a json solution.

As much as possible I'd want a free solution. Buying an app for such a simple thing would be overkill imo.

Comment: You can't (and shouldn't) reassign it systemwide.  App developers respect the system shortcuts so at minimum, you will have to do this for every app.   See this [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/299363/119271) for relevant info

Comment: The reason I do not want to do it for every app is because it is too tedious, moreover, "quit" is universal and must not differ between apps. Since my switch to mac, I found most mac shortcuts to be absurd. I have also used several other platforms before macos and very seldom do I have to remap keybindings. I do understand why you think I shouldn't and the risk this entails.

Comment: Not so much what "I" think, but what Apple Developer documentation spells out.

Comment: I've made a Karabiner-Elements rule that partly works. With it, Cmd+Q no longer works, but I can't seem to get Alt+F4 to do Cmd+Q's work. Posting it here in case someone can understand what's wrong with it and fix it up.
https://pastebin.com/Mp3RWUKn