# Keyboard shortcut conflict between Google Chrome and Facetime

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome, facetime

Google Chrome and Facetime app use the same keyboard shortcut (⌘ + control + f). In Google Chrome that keyboard shortcut toggles full-screen, and the same shortcut launches the Facetime app. When Google Chrome is the top-level application and I hit that keyboard shortcut, Facetime launches. I want Google Chrome to toggle full-screen. Currently, I don't know a way to toggle full screen with Google Chrome using the keyboard.

Is there a way to get the behavior I want? Can stop Facetime from launching with that shortcut? Can I remap Google Chrome shortcut to something else?

Comment: Hey Brian! See if this answers your query. There are some low-voted answers which are useful too!  [How to disable command-Q for Quit?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/78948/how-to-disable-command-q-for-quit)

Comment: That solution does work in my case, thus my question is a not duplicate. That remaps an overall keyboard shortcut. I need to remap an in-app keyboard shortcut. In the System Preferences, there is no way to control Facetime or Google Chrome specific shortcuts.

Comment: How does the said shortcut open FaceTime is what I wonder? It doesn't open FaceTime in my Mac. What OS version are you running?

Comment: I'm running MacOS 10.14.5

Comment: Here is the solution that works for me (which is different than How to disable command-Q for Quit? answer): 
Go to System Preferences, then Keyboard. Select Shortcuts. Under "All Applications", click on + symbol. 

Add "Enter Full Screen" as a new keyboard shortcut, such as shift+command+f.
Also add "Exit Full Screen" as a new keyboard shortcut, such as shift+command+f.

That will change it for all applications, including Google Chrome.